# htaccess not rewriting really well with hiding extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I am basically facing this problem with Rewrite. How?

So am trying to hide the:

```
example.php to /example
```

I got that working but now am facing another problem with other extensions. Thy is it rewriting?

```
WebPlayer.unity3d to WebPlayer.unity3d/
```

The `/` at the end I need that removed.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your .htaccess code looks right to me. What you could try is make a separate .htaccess for the folder WebPlayer.unity3d that does not have the conflicting code.

Good Luck!

Comment: This answer may not work for some things but, it seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `-Multiviews`

Try:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Did not work can't i make it check for unity3d and not rewrite?